# how to dismiss an existing popover and show another popover in a single touch in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

i'm having   a UItableView with lot of cells. Each cell is associated with different kind of popovers. When i touch a cell a popover will be shown. When i touch the other cell of the tableview i want to dismiss the existing popover and i've to show the popover corresponding to the selected cell.

But, when i touch the area outside the popover, the existing popover gets dismissed but i couldn't retrieve the cell index i've selected. Is there any way to  dismiss an existing popover and show another popover in a single touch in ipad?

Comment: Hi iPhony,

If you wanted to contribute to stackoverflow by providing answers for some problems you have encountered, it is always better to post the question, with clear description of what your problem is and then providing the solution in the Answer section. That would be easy for others.

Comment: @Shaggy something happened to the link you've put here. can you check it please? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved the Problem**

I've got the solution by setting passthroughView of the popover as the tableview in which i want to display the popover.

Comment: @Hamutsi Here is how you do it: `popoverViewController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't use passthroughView because I wanted my new popover be over the old one. So I used setContentViewController method.

I have a SplitViewController, that shows SettingsViewController in a popoverController and it can show a LoginViewController in the same popover, when user clicks a button in SettingsViewController.

This method is located in SplitViewController:

```
- (void)showLoginViewController
{
  if ( ! _myPopoverController.isPopoverVisible) {
    _myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.loginViewController];
    [_myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverOriginRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
  }
  else {
    [_myPopoverController setContentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:YES];
  }
}
```

I have a property in a SplitViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;
```

It is essential not to create a new instance of _myPopoverController but to set ContentViewController in old instance. It is a good practice to store PopoverController in a strong property, since it must not be deallocated while visible.